# Two "catalog_product_flat" identical products, is this normal?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, flat-catalog

Here is my intallation, 1 website (1 domain) with 2 store and each store view. "Use Flat Catalog Category" and "Use Flat Catalog Product" are enabled.

In my database, I therefore following tables:
catalog_category_flat_store_1
catalog_category_flat_store_2
catalog_product_flat_1
catalog_product_flat_2

In each table "catalog_category_flat_store" I have the corresponding categories for each store, store 1: Categories of my store 1 & 2 store: the category of my store 2 No worries..

But in my table "catalog_product_flat" I have all my products present in both tables, they are not dispatched in one or other of the two store based on their membership. Is this normal or am I missing a setting somewhere? Suddenly it increases the size of the database.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is perfectly normal.

This is because as you've said, you are using only 1 website with split stores/store views.

I would also assume that these products are then enabled for both store views and are only not visible due to not being added to that store/store views categories.

Comment: Thank you for your answer performadigital

I thought a "catalog_product_flat" there was only products belonging to the "root category" and its corresponding subcategories!

By cons I can not turn on and off this store Alike product on another store, since the scope of the activation is "website"!

Suddenly database is many times heavier as there are blind, is not it embarrassing?

Comment: Although this isn't directly related to your initial question. You can turn off products from being in particular websites. This is done under the 'Websites' tab when editing a product. Unfortunately yes, as you state, you can't do this between each store/storeview.

Answer (score 1):

One view = one flat database. We usually use views to make another language, that's why we need differents tables.